# Align element for width of left floated elemets

Tags: html, css

I need to align `.element` for width equal to total width number of `.block1` left floated elements. For different screens the number of `.block1` left floated elements fitted in one row will be different and their total width too. So how should I align .element?

```css
.block1 {
  width: 300px;
  float: left;
  background: #ccc;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: table;
}

.element {
  float: right;
  color: #fff;
  background: #000;
  padding: 10px;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}

.left {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1 class="left">My Title</h1>
  <div class="element">Element</div>

  <div class="clear"></div>

  <div class="block1">Block</div>
  <div class="block1">Block</div>
  <div class="block1">Block</div>
  <div class="block1">Block</div>
  <div class="block1">Block</div>
  <div class="block1">Block</div>
  <div class="block1">Block</div>
  <div class="block1">Block</div>
  <div class="block1">Block</div>
  <div class="block1">Block</div>
  <div class="block1">Block</div>
  <div class="block1">Block</div>
  <div class="block1">Block</div>
  <div class="block1">Block</div>
  <div class="block1">Block</div>
</div>
```

The `.element` is floated right near the right border of the browser, but I need the `.element` stand like on the print screen here for different screen width:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put all your `.block1` elements inside a common parent container, and use `media-queries` to vary the `width` of your `.parent` with screen size if you want to achieve what you are doing here.

Refer code:

```css
.block1 {
  width: 300px;
  float: left;
  background: #ccc;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: table;
}

.element {
  float: right;
  color: #fff;
  background: #000;
  padding: 10px;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}

.left {
  float: left;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 679px) {
  .parent {
    width: 330px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 680px) and (max-width: 980px) {
  .parent {
    width: 680px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1 class="left">My Title</h1>
  <div class="element">Element</div>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="block1">Block</div>
    <div class="block1">Block</div>
    <div class="block1">Block</div>
    <div class="block1">Block</div>
    <div class="block1">Block</div>
    <div class="block1">Block</div>
    <div class="block1">Block</div>
    <div class="block1">Block</div>
    <div class="block1">Block</div>
    <div class="block1">Block</div>
    <div class="block1">Block</div>
    <div class="block1">Block</div>
    <div class="block1">Block</div>
    <div class="block1">Block</div>
    <div class="block1">Block</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.wrapper {
    display: table;
    width:1020px;
}
```

you can give width parent div i.e wrapper

Comment: The point is that I need to fit as much as possible
 .block1 left floated elements in one row. So I could not strictly define the width like width:1020px;

Answer (score 0):

You can use following CSS for this

```
.block1 {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: calc(33% - 20px);
}
```